# How can I place a checkbox within a button?

Tags: html, css

I am using Bootstrap and want to place a checkbox within a button, similar to what is done with Gmail to select all messages. I have looked at the Gmail CSS but have been unable to determine how they've done it.

[image: checkbox button]

Comment: Inspect the element on the page. This will give you an idea.

Comment: i guess it just looks like button.. but its not a button..it could be a pill or just a div which looks like button

Comment: Hint - it's not actually a checkbox - it just looks like one.

Comment: It *can* be a checkbox, but as you said, it doesn't have to be. In my Q&D example/answer, I used an input type="checkbox" because it required less thought.

Comment: I thought the question was pretty straightforward but after a downvote and five people voting to put it on hold, apparently I've missed something. :) The answer from gibberish below, however, was very helpful and got me on the right track. I'm still learning the culture of SO, so am happy for any advice about why the question was too broad. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example, made of DIVs with some CSS and a little jQuery to check the checkbox when the button is clicked:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/crrojLho/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="btnOuterDIV">
        <div id="btnChkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="btnCB" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container  {padding:50px;}
#btnOuterDIV{height:30px;width:80px;border:1px solid #ccc;border-radius:5px;}
#btnOuterDIV:hover{border-color:#888;cursor:pointer;}
#btnChkbox{height:15px;width:15px;padding-top:5px;padding-left:5px;}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#btnOuterDIV').click(function(){
    alert('You clicked the button');
    $('#btnCB').prop('checked',true);
});
```

---

**Edit:**

Button text (a label) added to the button:  http://jsfiddle.net/crrojLho/2/

Comment: Really nice, it will be good to not click the button if you check the check box, but +1 from me !

Comment: Because it's a DIV containing an `<input type="checkbox">` element, one can tell exactly what element was clicked and decide to check/not check the checkbox as desired. jQuery totally rocks. *Thank you, Mr. Resig.*

Comment: Thanks for the help. The part I was missing was that in fact the "button" is not a button at all but just a div stylized to look like a button, making it much easier to put another item within it. With your example I'm able to accomplish what I'm looking for.

Comment: Glad to have helped -- and thanks for letting me know the upshot.